# angular-ui ng-grid external column grouping

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, ng-grid

The drag/drop and built in menu methods are fairly useful for the ngGrid script. I am currently trying to make it so that you can perform the column grouping via an external method such as a check box. This suites my needs more as it is more touch screen friendly. I've looked some at executing a manual groupBy() call, but that does not work for me at all.

Any ideas/help for this desire? The menu *can* work, but the drag/drop will not for a tablet unfortunately.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks.

**Figured it out:**

After some more playing around I was finally able to figure it out. I created a simple function:

```
$scope.updateGrouping = function(col) { $scope.gridOptions.groupBy(col); }
```

This works very simple where col is the name of the field. It also removes the grouping from the filter when the box is unchecked.